# IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist -- LOWER & CONTAINING usage

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, hql, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring Data JPA. I have this Query. `LOWER` function and `CONTAINING(case-insensitive)` are mandatory.

It's working fine, if i use :

```
findByCityContainsAndAreaContainsAndType(String city,String area, String type);
```

The reason for using @Query is i wanted to use joins. But ('%?1%') seems to be having an issue. 
Not sure how to implement it.

```
@Query(value=" select * from Agreement where LOWER(city) like LOWER('%?1%') and LOWER(AREA) like LOWER('%?2%') and type=?3", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Agreement> getAgreementDetailsByCityAreaAndType(String city,String area, String type);
```

Getting error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist
```

Also tried JPA:

```
@Query(value=" select sa from Agreement sa where LOWER(sa.city) like LOWER('%?1%') and LOWER(sa.area) like LOWER('%?2%') and sa.type=?3")
    public List<Agreement> getAgreementDetailsByCityAreaAndType(String city,String area, String type);
```

Same issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist
```

Also tried to use:

```
LOWER(city) like '%' + LOWER(?1) + '%'
```

from :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.execution

But it's throwing query syntax errors at run time.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: you want to work with jpa or native sql? as you have , nativeQuery = true

Comment: Updated original post now, i have even tried without nativeQuery. Same exception.

Comment: You have no need to put the "%" within the _LOWER_ when using JPQL.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you are using JPQL instead of native then i would suggest using the `concat` function:

```
@Query(value=" select sa from Agreement sa 
        where LOWER(sa.city) like LOWER(CONCAT('%', ?1, '%'))
          and LOWER(sa.area) like LOWER(CONCAT('%', ?2, '%')) and sa.type=?3")
    public List<Agreement> getAgreementDetailsByCityAreaAndType(String city,String area, String type);
```

I remember having some issues with the numbered parameters and had to use the named parameters. It was on an older version though so give it a try like above.